# how can do this in laravel with eloquent and db

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

how can do this in laravel with eloquent and db

```
SELECT thread.threadid, MATCH(thread.title) AGAINST ('title_seatch_word') AS score
FROM  thread AS thread
WHERE MATCH(thread.title) AGAINST ('title_seatch_word')
    AND thread.open <> 10
    " . iif($threadid, " AND thread.threadid <> $threadid") . "
LIMIT 5
```

i tray this

```
Thread::whereRaw('MATCH (`title`) AGAINST (?)', ['title_search_word'])
  ->where('open', '<>', 10)
  ->when(isset($threadid), function ($query) {return $query->where('threadid', '<>', $threadid);})
  ->take(5)
  ->get();
```

put i cant write this

```
SELECT thread.threadid, MATCH(thread.title) AGAINST ('title_seatch_word') AS score
```

so i want complete query

Comment: You can use `->select('thread.threadid',DB::raw("MATCH(thread.title) AGAINST ('title_seatch_word') AS score"))`

Comment: can write sql  complete

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Thread::select('threadid')
    ->selectRaw('MATCH (`title`) AGAINST (?) AS score', ['title_search_word'])
    ->where('open', '<>', 10)
    ->when(isset($threadid), function ($query) {
        return $query->where('threadid', '<>', $threadid);
    })
    ->havingRaw('`score`') // OR: ->having('score', '>', 0)
    ->take(5)
    ->get();
```

This way, `score` has to be calculated only once.

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answer?